# Add items to combobox in WPF within a canvas

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, combobox

Good day,

I want to add specific items to my combobox, but am running into an error.

Code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

[xml]$Form = @"

<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    Title="Printer GUI" Height="465" Width="375">
    <Canvas Background="White">
        <Label Name="label_username" Content="Username" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Name="label_Location" Content="Select Location" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="textbox_username" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="30,56,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <ComboBox Name="ComboBox_Location" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="X"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Y"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Z"/>
        </ComboBox>  
        <Label Name="label_printer" Content="Please select printer from list" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <ComboBox Name="ComboBox_Printer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300"/>
        <CheckBox Name="CheckBox" Content="Check here if you want to add this printer &#xA;&#x9;to your permanent list" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="56,185,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="245"/>
        <Button Name="Button_Add" Content="Add Printer" Margin="140,244,140,150" Width="75" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" ClickMode="Release"/>
        <Button Name="Button_XPS" Content="Printer Defaults issue&#xD;&#xA;  in Practice Partner" Margin="90,285,90,102" Width="175" Height="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" ClickMode="Release" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button Name="Button_Service" Content="Service call for Printer" Margin="113,343,110,51" Width="130" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" ClickMode="Release"/>
        <Button Name="Button_Cancel" Content="Cancel" Margin="140,384,140,10" Width="75" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" ClickMode="Release"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>

"@

$NR=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $Form)
$Win=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($NR)

$Win.Showdialog()
```

As you see, I tried to add items, but the error is as follows;

```
Cannot convert value "<Window xmlns=...</Window>" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument".
Error: "The 'Canvas' start tag on line 4 position 6 does not match the end tag of 
'ComboBox'. Line 12, position 11."
At H:\Scripts\Form_Main_XAML.ps1:3 char:1
+ [xml]$Form = @"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

This is my first time in Visual Studios, and this code has been a WinForms before this. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your block that says:

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBox_Location" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="X"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Y"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Z"/>
</ComboBox>
```

The first line ends in a `/>`, in which that closing tag designates the end of your ComboBox definition. Instead, you want to end it with `>` and let your corresponding `</ComboBox>` line close your block.

Comment: Thank you @Chris. I should've known it was a simple fix. I need to watch my openings and closings. Thank you for the explination!

Comment: @Megamidget3 No problem at all! Was by far one of my small annoyances when first learning XAML in VS. instinctively typing `/` to finish a tag, because it auto populates the `>`. My suggestion would be to get in a habit of creating your control, `<ComboBox` and if you know you’re going to have children nodes, immediately type `>` so that it auto fills the `</ComboBox>` for you and space it out so that it gives you a visual cue to put sub items in there.

Answer (score 0):

Your XAML combobox had a closing tag when it shouldn't:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    Title="Printer GUI" Height="465" Width="375">
    <Canvas Background="White">
        <Label Name="label_username" Content="Username" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Name="label_Location" Content="Select Location" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="textbox_username" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="30,56,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <ComboBox Name="ComboBox_Location" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="X"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Y"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Z"/>
        </ComboBox>  
        <Label Name="label_printer" Content="Please select printer from list" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <ComboBox Name="ComboBox_Printer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300"/>
        <CheckBox Name="CheckBox" Content="Check here if you want to add this printer &#xA;&#x9;to your permanent list" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="56,185,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="245"/>
        <Button Name="Button_Add" Content="Add Printer" Margin="140,244,140,150" Width="75" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" ClickMode="Release"/>
        <Button Name="Button_XPS" Content="Printer Defaults issue&#xD;&#xA;  in Practice Partner" Margin="90,285,90,102" Width="175" Height="40" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" ClickMode="Release" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button Name="Button_Service" Content="Service call for Printer" Margin="113,343,110,51" Width="130" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" ClickMode="Release"/>
        <Button Name="Button_Cancel" Content="Cancel" Margin="140,384,140,10" Width="75" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" ClickMode="Release"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```